# HikariCP freezes on addConnection()

Tags: mysql, hikaricp

I am using Hikari connection pool and i notice that HikariCP freezes. I took the thread dump and realize that it freezes on addConnection() method.

Here is my stack trace of the thread where HikariPool is being intiliazed

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc07c00c800 nid=0x3105 runnable [0x00007fc08275f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
        - locked <0x00000007d9f32408> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:620)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1102)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
        - locked <0x00000007d9f275b8> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor39.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:440)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:138)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:108)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool.addConnection(HikariPool.java:382)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool.fillPool(HikariPool.java:315)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:135)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:51)
```

Looking at the stack trace i do see that the thread is waiting on socketRead. But i am able to connect using mysql command line between the same two machines. Any thoughts whats going on ?

Comment: How many connections is MySQL configured for, and what is the configured pool size (max)?  Maybe post your relevant MySQL configuration settings, and complete pool configuration.

Comment: Also, this [C3P0 thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/c3p0/bugs/52/) seems relevant.  If you have autoReconnect=true for the JDBC driver, and there is something wrong with the connection URL, it will keep trying to connect and exhibit this symptom.

Comment: @brettw Mysql is configured for 1000 connections. My server app is trying to create 100. Application and MySQL are on different physical hosts.

Comment: Again, you are setting autoReconnect=true that will cause a problem.  If the driver is blocking in the MySQL driver's connect code, it is not a pool issue.

Comment: @brettw, we see the same issue with autoReconnect=false. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649479/is-there-a-way-to-configure-hikari-to-fail-fast-if-the-database-connection-dat) has some sample code if you'd like to try it.

Comment: wondering if this is simply the mysql driver connect code or something else?