# Is there a way to configure Hikari to "fail fast" if the database connection data is invalid?

Tags: hikaricp

Running this test with an invalid hostname, or user/password, it waits about 2 minutes before failing. I would ideally like to have it fail immediately if user/password is incorrect, or if the hostname/port are not correct.

```
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
    config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_one?useServerPrepStmts=true&autoReconnect=false");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("port", "3306");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "project_one");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", "root");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", "");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("autoReconnect", false);

    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
```

Comment: There is a fail-fast option (see below), but "how fast" may depend on driver settings.  See the MySQL [properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for details.  Search that page for 'timeout' and you'll find several timeouts that might affect how long it takes HikariCP to detect a failed connection attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, release 1.2.9 introduced a fail-fast option (current release is 1.3.3).  The configuration property is `initializationFailFast`.  Set that to true, and the pool should fail quickly.  Enabling debug logging for `com.zaxxer.hikari` in your logging framework (log4j, slf4j, etc) can provide more details about why the connection failure occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. With debug on, I do see these messages, one for each of the setMinimumPoolSize value (plus one more I think): "[main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Maximum connection creation retries exceeded"

Comment: It appears to be a little faster, but if my min pool size is a big number, it'll still try once for each. I don't suppose there's any way around that though (and not a big deal for us).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v3.0.0 of HikariCP, you have to use the property `initializationFailTimeout`.

The property `initializationFailFast` was deprecated in v2.4.10 and removed in v3.0.0.

Related issue [#770](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/770) and pull request [#771](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/pull/771)